# Local temporary tables fail on SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server-2000

I am just trying to implement the following code sample on our SQL Server 2000 database:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;q248915

The problem appears when I try and create the "expand" stored procedure which produces the following errors:

> *Error code 156, SQL state S1000: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.
>
>   Error code 156, SQL state S1000: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN'.
>
>   Error code 156, SQL state S1000: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
>
>   Error code 156, SQL state S1000: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
>
>   Error code 156, SQL state S1000: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.*

It appears that I can't create local temporary tables as the following SQL demonstrates:

```
CREATE TABLE #Yaks (YakID int,YakName char(30))
```

> *Error code 170, SQL state 37000: Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE'.*

Does anybody have any idea why I can't create temporary tables? Especially when article says the code applies to Microsoft SQL Server 2000.

Thanks

**UPDATE**: It appears this might be an issue with NetBeans SQL Editor as the query works fine when used within SQL Server Query Analyser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug within NetBeans itself, which has now been resolved:

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=222617